# how to insert a python variable inside a hyperlink in html using Django?

Tags: python, django, hyperlink

In this html block:

```
{% block body %}
    <h1>All Pages</h1>

    <ul>
        {% for x in entries %}
            {% comment %} {% wik = 'mask/' + x + '.md' %} {% endcomment %}
            <li><a href = 'mask/'{{x}} </a>{{ x }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endblock %}
```

I am trying to insert a string in `x` that will go to end of the hypertext. `mask/cat`, where "cat" is x [just as an example]. When I do this, the `entry` does not seem to be added to the hyperlink when I click it.

The other way I thought is to create a python variable `wik` with the correct page hyperlink, but then I get an issue in Django

```
Invalid block tag on line 12: 'wik', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

Any help appreciated
thanks

Comment: Have you considered using URL patterns: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns?

Comment: OK -- thanks -- I'll review the url patterns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is that your variable is outside of the href, this should work:

`<li><a href = 'mask/{{x}}' </a>{{ x }}</li>`

If it's a variable based url on your app though, I would consider using a url pattern for a cleaner solution

Comment: Thank you, @Danielle! I'll take  a look at thay